# extending native session class codeigniter 1.7.2

Tags: class, codeigniter, session, native, extend

I'm using native session library to replace the built in session library in CI. I need to extend the class but when I drop in MY_Session.php, CI reverts back to the old /system/libraries/Session.php.

How to I extend a class that's replaced a core CI class like Session.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Simply by naming your class files identically to a native library will
>   cause CodeIgniter to use it instead of the native one. To use this
>   feature you must name the file and the class declaration exactly the
>   same as the native library. For example, to replace the native Email
>   library you'll create a **file named application/libraries/Email.php**
>
> -user guide

then call it

```
class MY_Email extends CI_Email {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Loading Your Sub-class:

```
$this->load->library('email');
```

**EDIT**
Try this:

Just load your new library (the one doing the extending):

Then, let's say we have Session.php and Mysession.php

```
<?php
load_class('session', false);

class Mysession extends Session {
   //your code
}
```

You don't need the MY_ name tag still, I think you want to reserve that for it's original intended purpose to avoid confusion.

.. else just use an include() or require() :P

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Maybe I didn't explain what I need to do well. I'm using this library http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Session_Hybrid .. I dropped the Session.php file in application/libraries/ and create a MY_Session.php file to extend the custom session class but when I do this it defaults back to CI's native session management. I was trying to figure out a way to override the custom class's methods without modifiying it's code.

Comment: You don't need the MY_ in the filename.  Just name it Session.php and it'll replace the old one.

Comment: Ok let me explain a bit more. I've taken Session.php from the custom Session Hybrid library and dropped it in my /application/libraries folder. Now I want to extend this custom library without replacing code in the file. When I create MY_Session.php in the library folder it doesn't load /application/libraries/Session.php anymore. It defaults back to /system/libraries/Session.php. Make more sense ?? :)

Comment: Ok, i get what you're after now. Edited answer. Sorry for being dense :P

Comment: That works. Thanks for the answer. I was curious if their was a way to use MY_ tag but I guess that's only intended for extending the CI native classes. Thanks again.